# How do I pickle and unpickle a list of MultiDiGraphs created with NetworkX?

Tags: list, pickle, networkx

I have a list of MultiDiGraphs (directed graphs that allow more than one edge between each pair of nodes) that I have created using NetworkX. I have stored these graphs in a list. Now, I would like to pickle this list, so I can use it in the future -I know I could use other methods of storage but I am particularly interested in this one-.

I would also like to be able to load the pickled information into another list of graphs if I want to use it in the future.

Could anyone tell me how to pickle and unpickle this kind of object? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I use `cPickle` for python2 (it's faster) but `pickle` for python3, so `import` accordingly depending on what python you use.

```
import cPickle as pickle  # python2
import pickle  # python3
import networkx as nx

# Make graph
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,2),(3,4),(1,3)])

# Dump graph
with open("/path/to/file/multigraph.p", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(G, f)

# Load graph
with open("/path/to/file/multigraph.p", 'rb') as f:  # notice the r instead of w
    G_loaded = pickle.load(f)
```

As simple as that.

**[EDIT]** To `pickle.dump` a list of graphs:

```
# Dump List of graphs

l = [G, G_loaded]
with open("/path/to/file/multigraph.p", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(l, f)

# Load List of graphs

with open("/path/to/file/multigraph.p", 'rb') as f:
    l_load = pickle.load(f)
```

Now `l_load[0]` contains multigraph `G`.

Comment: Thank you @rodgdor, this is very helpful, although it works for just one graph. I was wondering how I can loop over a list of graphs to pickle (unpickle) them to (from) the same .pkl file. For a text file, I know I can for example store each element of the list on a new line, but for the case of .pkl files, I do not have an intuition of how things are stored.

Comment: It is sorted now, thanks for your hint @rodgdor. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem, consider accepting the answer if it fits your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the networkx intra-library util methods were available back in 2017, but for current (2020) reference, you can use:

`gpickle` module in `networkx.readwrite`

Something like the pseudocode below. Under the hood, the method is essentially doing the same thing, i.e., calling pickle.dummp(list, path)

```
# Gs : List[nx.MultiGraph] = [gs1, gs2,...,gsT]
out_fp = f'{data_dir}/{dataset}/graphs'
logger.info(f'| saving nx.Graphs  outputs to {out_fp}/{output_prefix}_*.gpickle')
nx.write_gpickle(Gs, f"{out_fp}/{output_prefix}_Gs.gpickle")
```

Comment: The main point about this answer is not only using the internal library but storing the different graphs in different files that are named by some id of the graph. I believe the internal library does not store a list of graphs. The way this answer is written it will not work, I believe.

Comment: Deprecated since version 2.6. See: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gpickle.read_gpickle.html